# How to add a column and row at the end of 2d array?

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to add a row and column at the end of my 2D array whenever the function is called.

```
template <typename vertex> void directed_graph<vertex>::add_vertex(const vertex& u) 
{
    if (!directed_graph<vertex>::contains(u))
    {
        vertices.push_back(u);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < vertices.size()-1; i ++)
            {
                adj_matrix[i].resize(vertices.size());
                adj_matrix[i][vertices.size()-1] = false;
            }

        adj_matrix.resize(vertices.size());
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i ++)
        {
            adj_matrix[vertices.size()-1][i] = false;
        }   
    }
}
```

I tried this code as above and I received is the SegFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you try to do

You intend to grow an `n*n` adjacency matrix to an `(n+1)*(n+1)`, where `n` is `vertices.size()-1`,  after your initial `push_back()` in the `vertices` vector.

This looks (almost) fine:

- Your first `for`-loop resizes the `n` existing inner vectors, adding de facto the missing column.
- You then resize the outer vector, which adds a default constructed (empty) vector at the end.
- Then in the second `for`-loop, you try to initialize the new inner vector by directly assigning a value to its elements.

### What's wrong here ?

Unfortunately when you do this last step,  the last inner vector is still empty. So your second for loop uses an out-of-range subscript `i`, which causes UB (possible symptom: seg fault).

### How to solve it ?

All you need to do, is to resize the last inner vector before your second loop:

```
...
adj_matrix.resize(vertices.size());
adj_matrix[vertices.size()-1].resize(vertices.size());  //<<-- this is missing !
for (unsigned i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i ++) 
...
```